# Zlib difference between Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, zlib

So I'm rewriting a relatively complex script from Python into Ruby (as a part of rebuilding the whole legacy app).
Everything worked out just fine, except 1 point, where I need to compress a string to a certain format.

Here's the original Python code:

```
 gz = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
 zstr = gz.compress(jcomment) + gz.flush()
```

Here's my Ruby equivalent:

```
gz = Zlib::Deflate.new 9, Zlib::MAX_WBITS | 16
zstr = gz.deflate(jcomment) + gz.flush(Zlib::FINISH)
```

But it's nowhere near the same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Python3](https://eval.in/private/218ffe66e3b623) has the same result as [Ruby](https://eval.in/private/beab37209801b1). Maybe looking up `zlib` changes between 2 and 3 might help.

Comment: Looks like there are differences in zlib implementation in python2 and python3 that are not documented.